# Android PopupMenu отображение при старте

Tags: android, mvp, autocompletetextview, rotation, popupmenu

Есть элемент `AutoCompleteTextView` при нажатии на который появляется `PopupMenu`.
***Как мне при старте приложения отобразить этот список автоматически?***
Приложение реализует `MVP` поэтому запуск должен быть из Presenter;
Варианты с `OnChangeFocus` - не подходят, потому что нужно сделать так, чтобы при смене ориентации сохранялось состояние (если было открыто - открыть, если было закрыто - закрыть);
Варианты с таймером тоже не подходят(решение нужно оптимальное даже для старых устройств, на которых невозможно просчитать время, и в то же время быстрым на новых аппаратах);
Варианты с `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` тоже не подходят, потому что нужно чтобы Activity полноценно пересоздавалась

Когда я пытаюсь открыть меню в `onCreate()`, `onStart()`, `onResume()` - получаю `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException`
я могу открыть его только в `onAttachedToWindow()`, но из presenter'а этот метод не вызывается

Comment: каждый раз при старте должно быть отображение или только один раз?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, 
При старте показать.  
Если пользователь повернул экран - показать.  Если пользователь убрал его и повернул экран - не показывать.

Comment: Пользователь снова отобразил его и повернул экран - показать

Comment: а вы смотрели в сторону sharedpreferences?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, Не понимаю как они связаны с отображением меню. Я могу сохранить элементы и состояние открытия/закрытия. Я не могу отобразить меню ни в `onCreate()`, ни в `onStart()`, ни в 'onResume()`

Comment: если у вас проблемы с отображением то покажите как вы его пытаетесь показать